# Gender and etymology of name "Herena"

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, names, christianity, late-latin

I found that Herena is the name of a [Christian saint from the 3rd century](https://catholicsaints.info/book-of-saints-donatus-justus-herena-and-others/). Virtually nothing is known about Herena's life, but my question is about the name:

Is it a feminine name or masculine, or can it apply to either gender?

Is there a known etymology for that name?

Comment: Not an answer, but I notice that empress Irene of Athens (d. 803) is called "Herena" in the Royal Frankish Annals: https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Annales_regni_Francorum – St. Irene of Rome (d. 288, known for saving the life of St. Sebastian) is also very rarely called Herena, for example in this German encyclopedia from 1844: https://books.google.de/books?id=8vJMAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA388&q=herena